# How to check the number of days when the last time the user was bound to LDAP

Tags: authentication, active-directory, ldap, phpldapadmin

I have a project that adds user profile to LDAP Server.
This LDAP server is being used by other web system for their login authentication.

I have this new requirement that should count the days starting from the date when the user was added to LDAP and until the date the user login its username and password.

If the count of days is 90 days and the user never used the username and password from the date the user was added in LDAP, then my web system should send an email to the user that its access will be revoked the next day.

My problem is, I know that LDAP is only to store user information.
Is there any way on how I can determine all the request to the LDAP server (any system)
pulls user information in LDAP and started counting.

Please give me some light.  :(

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The AD schema probably already supports all this.

Comment: hello @user207421 the current department was using PHPAdminLDAP, I was reading its documentation and I cannot find this feature with report generation like the Microsoft Active Directory. :(